# Constructor of inner class with ifstream member returns invalid fstream

Tags: c++, access-violation, ifstream

I have a class with an inner class which has a member ifstream. When executing the code throws an AccessViolationException in `TestDataHelper::getNextLine()` at `if(!datafile->eof())`.

Debugging showed me that the constructor is working fine. The file is created and the first line is read. But when I check the datafile after the assignment is done (after `TestDataHelper helper = TestDataHelper("data.csv");`), the datafile becomes an invalid pointer.

The code:

IfstreamTester.h

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class IfstreamTester
{
public:
    IfstreamTester(void);
    ~IfstreamTester(void);

    void doStuff();

private:
    std::ifstream file;

    class TestDataHelper{
    private:
        std::ifstream *datafile;
    public:
        TestDataHelper(std::string filename);
        ~TestDataHelper();
        std::vector<double>* getNextLine();
    };
};
```

IfstreamTester.cpp

```
#include "IfstreamTester.h"

using namespace std;

IfstreamTester::IfstreamTester(void)
{}

IfstreamTester::~IfstreamTester(void)
{}

void IfstreamTester::doStuff()
{
    TestDataHelper helper = TestDataHelper("data.csv");
    // for every line in the file
    vector<double>* v;
    do
    {
        v = helper.getNextLine();
        cout << v << endl;
        delete v;
    } while(v != NULL);
}

IfstreamTester::TestDataHelper::TestDataHelper(std::string filename)
{
    datafile = new ifstream(filename.c_str());
    // read the header line
    string line;
    getline(*datafile, line);
}

vector<double>* IfstreamTester::TestDataHelper::getNextLine()
{
    if(!datafile->eof())
    {
        // readline
        string line = "";
        getline(*datafile, line);
        string delimiter = ",";
        vector<double>* res = new vector<double>();
        size_t pos = 0;
        // and tokenize line into vector of doubles
        while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            stringstream conv;            
            double token;
            conv << line.substr(0, pos);
            conv >> token;
            res->push_back(token);
            line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        }
        return res;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

IfstreamTester::TestDataHelper::~TestDataHelper()
{
    datafile->close();
    delete datafile;
}
```

and the main:

```
#include "IfstreamTester.h"

void main()
{
    IfstreamTester s = IfstreamTester();
    s.doStuff();
}
```

Anyone an idea why this is so?

**EDIT:** I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler isn't doing you any favors. It should be puking, telling you [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) isn't copyable and the default copy-constructor of its containing parent , `IfstreamTester`, should therefore also be implicitly deleted.

I don't know what toolchain you're using, but clang++ 3.3 and g++ 4.7 both puke on this. Your compiler is apparently allowing it through because of a copy-elision assumption, then failing to actually elide the copy in debug. Either add a copy-constructor that *doesn't* member copy the `std::ifstream` member, or declare `main()` as:

```
int main()
{
    IfstreamTester s;
    s.doStuff();
}
```

The non-standard `void main()` declaration in your code has me (likely incorrectly) deducing you're using either an MS or Borland toolchain. Whoever is allowing this (both the odd `main()` and the non-copyable `std::ifstream` member to be copied), isn't playing by the rules.

Comment: Making the copy constructor, the assignment operator private and adapting the code respectively solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`while(v != NULL)` looks fairly wrong. Also did you mean to write your loop as follows?

```
vector<double>* v = NULL;
do
{
    v = helper.getNextLine();
    cout << v << endl;
    delete v;
} while(v != NULL);
```

Comment: getNextLine is made such that it returns a NULL pointer when the end is reached.

But anyway, this is not remotely explaining nor solving the problem of the ifstream object becoming invalid after the assigmnent constructor call.

Comment: @MikedeDood At least this was to long for a comment. As for your problems with `ifstream*` becoming invalid, I'd recommend using a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer. You're closing and deleting the `ifstream*` in your `TestDataHelper` destructor, this is a violation of the [rule-of-three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three/4172724#4172724) principles.

Comment: I cannot use std::unique_ptr (it is c++98 and boost may not be used).

Comment: @MikedeDood Why aren't you using a plain instance of `ifstream` (not to be copied), and the filename as a separate member? You can use the `ifstream::open()` separately then. You don't need to call `close()` on destruction BTW.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I want to have an object that on construction opens the file and with every call of getNextLine reads the next line in the file and parses it into a vector of doubles. I don't see how that could work without having the file as class member.

Comment: @MikedeDood You **can** use `ifstream::open()` in the constructor of your helper class. _'work without having the file as class member'_ I didn't say you should have no member, but instead of a `ifstream*` have a plain `ifstream` instance as member.

Answer (score 0):

I tried do compile this using g++ 4.6.3:

I had to add `#include <fstream>` and change `IfstreamTester s = IfstreamTester();` to `IfstreamTester s;`